# Copy a Kendo UI Vue Design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-vue

i consider myself a good developer but when it comes to design or struggle with bootstrap or css stuff i'm lost.
so i came here to ask for some help.

i'm using kendo ui with vue.
now i need to do a couple of cruds, and i was asked to copy the design of the following [page](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap/).
[image: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bootstrap/]

well the thing is that i'm unable to copy that design... :(
not even the design, the controls don't look like that at all.

can someone point me in the right direction?
i don't even find that panel on kendo-vue.

thanks.
regards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the source of the page. You will be able to see the css classes that are being used. What is more you could spot the stylesheets being used and lookup the their sources.

Secondly, you don't want to look for the whole panel on kendo-vue. Look for different components to assemble the panel: form, inputs, datepickers, selects etc.

Thirdly, you could view the whole theme on [github](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-bootstrap-demo) . Just clone it and add your changes

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, i didn't know about that github repo. i will take a look.

Comment: well, after one hour trying to figure out how to get that working, i'm giving up.

Comment: the thing is i don't know if i'm missing from importing something, i'm using bootstrap-vue, maybe that's the problem with that.

Comment: please share the code that you've written. Exactly the form part

Comment: you are using plain html style for elements tags whether you should link components in vue style https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/framework/using-cdn/